# Can ZF prove the cartesian product of an ordinal by itself to be subnumerous to that ordinal?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, ordinals

Does ZF (without choice) prove the following?

$\forall \ ordinal \ \alpha \ \exists f( f:\alpha \times \alpha \hookrightarrow \alpha)$

where: $ \alpha\times \alpha $ is the cartesian product of $\alpha$ by itself; and $\hookrightarrow$ signifies *injection*.

Comment: Yes, $|\alpha\times \alpha|=|\alpha|$ for ordinals in ZF. (This is usually proven with the pairing function.)

Comment: but the pairing function is form ordered pairs of naturals to naturals, can this be generalized over all ordinals?

Comment: Yes. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112079/what-is-g%C3%B6dels-pairing-function-on-ordinals (Also, the usual proof of the result that uses this function is available in e.g. Jech or Kunen.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, Thank you!